# Does Windows 7 have unzip at the command line installed by default?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, zip

There is a zip/unzip option in the context menu so is it accessible from the command line?

Answer (score 28):

Yes and no.

The yes:

`rundll32.exe zipfldr.dll,RouteTheCall filename.zip`

would open the file in the explorer as a "compressed folder" similar to clicking open a zip folder

The no:

There is no other entry point in zipfldr.dll that allows decompressing files directly from command line. I would suggest using the 7zip command utilities or unzip.exe as these are free (as in freedom as well as in beer)

Answer (score 5):

If you already have Java JDK on your PC, and the bin directory is in your path (in most cases), you can use the command line:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin>jar xf test.zip
```

Complete set of options for the jar tool available [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html).

Examples:

Extract jar file

```
jar x[v]f jarfile [inputfiles] [-Joption]
jar x[v] [inputfiles] [-Joption]
```

If you don't have JDK installed I would recommend installing 7-Zip, since it's very lightweight: http://www.7-zip.org/

Examples: http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1021592/475876

Comment: Good suggestion! It's 3rd party package that probably exist on server and allows to avoid installing additional software that may cause additional security risks.

Answer (score 2):

As Jason Duffett's reply

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546016/how-can-you-zip-or-unzip-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-ca

you can try "expand MyFile.zip myFile" in cmd line

Comment: As the comments on the [SO] answer point out, this works only for ``.CAB`` files, not zip files.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: sorry for my careless, my reply is for .CAB not for zip files. Thanks for correct.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't by default, but check here to do it anyway: http://stahlworks.com/dev/index.php?tool=zipunzip