# Creating a zip archive from Windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, zip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create .zip folder from the command line - (Windows)](https://superuser.com/questions/201371/create-zip-folder-from-the-command-line-windows)

Is it possible to create a zip archive from the Windows command line without any 3rd party tools (7-Zip, WinZip, etc.)?

Comment: No, there is no command line compression tool built into windows as far as I know.

Comment: But it is possible to create a script that will be able to use Windows built-in zip capabilities. See [this question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211/can-windows-built-in-zip-compression-be-scripted).