# How can I automate zipping and deletion of directories using built-in Windows Server Zip?

Tags: command-line, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, zip, windows-server-2003

I am looking to get some up-to-date advice on how to automate the following process within Windows Server (no 3rd-party utils can be used)..

1. Zip directories (sometimes nested e.g. daily_stuff/hourly_stuff/)
2. Validate the source directory and the zip file have same content
3. Delete the source directory
4. (Optional) - Move the ZIP file to location Y from location X

Systems are Windows Server 2003 (I know I know, they're upgrading soon!) and some Windows Server 2008..

Thanks in advance for your advice

Comment: Is it possible to use powershell? Maybe this would help: http://serverfault.com/a/456496/64942

Comment: powershell is not already installed on the Server 2003 machines so cannot be added at this stage I'm afraid

Comment: How would you validate it? Seems redundant.

Comment: Try to get something built and report back if you're having trouble getting parts of it to work as expected. Here's a resource with several other resources and answers within plus with the above, these are good starting points for you: http://superuser.com/questions/201371/create-zip-folder-from-the-command-line-windows. If PowerShell is possible, then I'd suggest shooting for that; otherwise, 7Zip is a free open-source utilize or else look at some of these resources and take a stab at somethign and see what progess you make -- update your question with the logic you come up with though.

Comment: Just as FYI, you can run 7Zip on Windows and WITHOUT installing it too, just do some Google searches and some reading and you should be able to figure this out to put something in place for testing. In any case, put something in place and test and post what you try that does not work and people can help getting that to work for you.

Comment: You can use VBS.  But, as-is, I think this question is a little too broad.  Check out Stackoverflow: [Can Windows' built-in ZIP compression be scripted?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211/can-windows-built-in-zip-compression-be-scripted?rq=1), [How to unzip a file in VBScript using internal Windows XP options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911053/how-to-unzip-a-file-in-vbscript-using-internal-windows-xp-options-in)

Comment: I think this question could be considered a duplicate of the SU question pointed out by @LMFAO_A_JOKE [Create .zip folder from the command line - (Windows)](http://superuser.com/questions/201371/create-zip-folder-from-the-command-line-windows)

Comment: Thank you all for your responses - here are some considerations:

- absolutely no third-party applications can be used/installed in the environment, hence the requirement for a windows-server-2003-only solution using built-in tools

- non-installed 3rd-party applications are also not a viable option at this time

-