# Is Windows 10 shipped with tools that can un(zip) with the format ZIP64?

Tags: zip

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)) states that `The File Explorer in Windows XP does not support ZIP64, but the Explorer in Windows Vista and later do.[citation needed]`, but I have not been able to find a confirming source.

Is Windows 10 shipped with tools that can `un-zip` and `zip` with the format `ZIP64`, and if so, what tool(s)?

Comment: Windows 10 File Explorer can un-zip and show any modern ZIP file. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I have clarified the question.

Comment: Windows 10 does not ship with an "unzipper"  It can show files in Windows Explorer.  I use WinZip V25 for true Zip work.

Comment: The windows shell has a built in "unzipper".  Right drag a zip file and select "extract".  If you want it from the command line, you can use powershell directly `PowerShell Expand-Archive -Path "source_zip_file_path" -DestinationPath "folder_you_want_unzipped_to"`.  I am not sure about zip64, TRY IT.  Also 7zip is the best TRUE free tool out there and also supports rar and 7zip own (superior) format.

Comment: I just found this page too.  It points out that windows 10 comes with tar.exe which (unlike posix tar) can create compressed zips. https://superuser.com/questions/201371/create-zip-folder-from-the-command-line-windows