# Using a .bat file to pull a string from a text file within a zip folder

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, zip

So, please bear with me. This is only the second batch file I've ever written and my first post anywhere on StackExchange.

I'm writing a batch file that tells a remote server to run HP Array Diagnostic Utility and pull the report back to my computer. I'm extremely excited because it's working very well, for the most part. I do have one minor issue, though. I'm trying to pull the serial number from the text file within the zip folder that comes from the remote server. When I pull the information from a test text file not inside a compressed folder, this part of the code works. It doesn't work when the text file is in the zip folder, though. Is there a way to get this to work?

Here is the portion of the code in question:

```
FOR /f "tokens=1-4 delims= " %%A IN ("%userprofile%\Desktop\report.zip\report.txt") DO (
 IF %%A ==Chassis (
    SET "sn=%%D"
    ECHO %sn%
 )
)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Decompress the zip file to a temp folder, read the file, delete the temp folder. For help with that see [Does Windows 7 have unzip at the command line installed by default?](http://superuser.com/questions/149489/does-windows-7-have-unzip-at-the-command-line-installed-by-default)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Despite the fact Windows displays `.zip` archives as compressed folders, they're not *real* folders at all. This means you can't directly access the compressed content until you extract it somewhere.

Windows doesn't provide a command-line utility to extract (or create, for the matter) compressed archives. With a little VBScript, you can however bypass this limitation:

```
REM^ &@echo off
REM^ &if not exist "%~f1" exit /b 2
REM^ &md "%temp%\%~nx1" 2>nul
REM^ &cscript /nologo /e:vbscript "%~f0" "%~f1" "%temp%\%~nx1"
REM^ &exit /b

Set sa = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set files = sa.NameSpace(WScript.Arguments(0)).Items
Set target = sa.NameSpace(WScript.Arguments(1))

For Each file In files
target.CopyHere file, 1556
Next
```

### How it works

The above script is a hybrid (thanks to dbenham and jeb for the idea), and contains both regular batch and VBScript commands in a single file.

The script accepts only one parameter, which is the archive path. At first the script checks whether the specified file actually exists, and then proceeds creating a subfolder named after the archive in the built-in temporary folder.

The VBScript code is then executed. Each file in the archive gets copied (extracted) to the target folder. The option value is `1556`, which corresponds to `4 + 16 + 512 + 1024` and is required to make the whole operation unattended by skipping confirmation prompts (see the link below for additional details).

### Example usage

```
@echo off
setlocal

set archive=report.zip
call UnzipHelper.cmd "%userprofile%\Desktop\%archive%" >nul
pushd "%temp%\%archive%"

REM your code here

popd
rd /s /q "%temp%\%archive%" 2>nul

pause
endlocal & exit /b
```

### Further reading

- [Command-Line Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx)
- [UNZIP with System.Shell Folder's CopyHere method](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_files_zip.php#CopyHereUNZIP)
- [Is it possible to embed and execute VBScript within a batch file without using a temporary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9074476/is-it-possible-to-embed-and-execute-vbscript-within-a-batch-file-without-using-a)

Comment: I've never done VBScript before. Thank you for the information and the resources. Something new to play with.